Android Auto Integration with mobile (Kotlin)
I am currently working on the project on my android studio and successfully build a stable mobile app and wearable that will synced real time data from the mobile app. however, i have hard time trying to integrate my app to android auto. there are some API that cannot be done like wear so i finding it very absurd to do.
the simple thing i want to do is fetch the logged in id from mobile and display it on the auto. more like connection issue between mobile and auto
I have try to use a wearable API to integrate with my auto but of course it wont allow you because auto have different API. I am expecting to have a full step by step how to connect to the mobile for my auto

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
